# jquery return specific input field

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Im trying to change the value of an input field inside a div element "Cellbox"
i have tried

```
$('#CellBox').$(':input').val("Something");
$('#CellBox :input').val("Something");
$('#CellBox:input').val("Something");
$(':input #CellBox').val("Something");
```

nothing..

Edit:
thanks guys, 
it was a mispelling - the most common error...
The

```
$('#CellBox :input').val("Something");
```

is correct

Comment: you have not tried $(':input#CellBox').val("Something") - ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Number 2 would have worked as it looks for an element with the id `CellBox` with a field of type `input` within it:

```
$('#CellBox :input').val("Something");
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/VzsjG/

What was wrong with the others?

Number 1:

```
$('#CellBox').$(':input').val("Something");
```

Was a syntax error, just plain wrong - although it was close... if you would have used `.find` in place of the second `$` it would have worked (Eg: http://jsfiddle.net/4s5RJ/)

Number 3:

```
$('#CellBox:input').val("Something");
```

This incorrectly looks for an element with the id `CellBox` *which is itself of type input*

Number 4:

```
$(':input #CellBox').val("Something");
```

This looks for an element of type input with an element inside it with the id `CellBox` (ie, the wrong way round)

Answer (score 5):

```
$('#CellBox input').val("Something");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#CellBox').find('input').val("Something");
```